# Issue with Oracle SQL where statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**Hi everyone, am new to SQL and am encountering the following problem when i execute a simple select command. Below is the codes:**

## SQL:

```
select cheffname
from speciality
where speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine';
```

## Output:

```
Daniel
Pamela
Sarah
```

## SQL:

```
select cheffname
from speciality
where speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine';
```

## Output:

```
Daniel
Jerry
```

## SQL

```
select cheffname
from speciality
where speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine' and speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine';
```

## Output:

```
no rows selected
```

**As you can see, I would expect the 3rd SQL Query to return `Daniel` but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Do you mean to use `OR`? `Chinese Cuisine` will never equal `Japanese Cuisine`.

Comment: Not possible that way, because you don't have a `single row` that has two values in it ... you looking for row that has speciality both Chinese and Japanese cusines ... because operator `and` ... if you want to find cheff who knows both Chinese and Japanese cusine, you have to tweak query a bit

Comment: The classic way is OR or UNION/UNION ALL as Jacob H suggested.

Comment: How did your queries *ever* return `Daniel` for both queries? The field `speciality` can only contain a single value, so it will *either* be equal to "Chinese Cuisine" OR "Japanese Cuisine" - it can't be equal to both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INTERSECT`  is one option.

```
SELECT cheffname
FROM speciality
WHERE speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine'
 INTERSECT
SELECT cheffname
FROM speciality
WHERE speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine'
```

Comment: @newcoder69 : You're welcome. Do try Gordon's answer after the edit

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want:

```
select cheffname
from speciality
where speciality in ('Chinese Cuisine', 'Japanese Cuisine')
group by cheffname
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Im sorry but this getting this error : ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT cheffname
FROM speciality
WHERE cheffname IN (
        SELECT cheffname
        FROM speciality
        WHERE speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine'
        )
    AND cheffname IN (
        SELECT cheffname
        FROM speciality
        WHERE speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine'
        )
```

Comment: Nope, still don't get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

you got 'no rows selected' because this query,

```
select cheffname from speciality where speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine' and speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine';
```

returns rows when both conditions in where clause are true,in your case its never possible because you wrote 2 conditions on same column speciality.I hope u understand it and u can get desired output by several ways one of them is,

```
select cheffname from speciality where speciality = 'Chinese Cuisine'
union
select cheffname from speciality where speciality = 'Japanese Cuisine'
```